# Security strength of JPBC Type A curve compared to SecP curve

Tags: elliptic-curves, key-size, pairings

I recently encountered some problems when learning about the [JPBC library](http://gas.dia.unisa.it/projects/jpbc/).

Does the curve generated by (J)PBC using the method `typeAcurvegenerator(160,512)` and the curve secp160k1 achieve the same 80 bit security level?

How should I understand the terms *qbit* and *rbit*?